# removing null value from string

Tags: sql, database, null, case

I want to show the translated name and description with language_id 'us' and 'ru'. My question is how can I remove the null values?

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN LANGUAGE_ID = 'US' THEN COALESCE(TO_CHAR(TRANSLATED_NAME), ' ')
       END AS PRODUCT_NAME_US,
       CASE WHEN LANGUAGE_ID = 'US' THEN INITCAP(CONCAT(SUBSTR(TRANSLATED_DESCRIPTION, 1, 30), '...'))
       END AS PRODUCT_DESC_US,
       CASE WHEN LANGUAGE_ID = 'RU' THEN COALESCE(TO_CHAR(TRANSLATED_NAME), ' ')
       END AS PRODUCT_NAME_RU,
       CASE WHEN LANGUAGE_ID = 'RU' THEN INITCAP(CONCAT(SUBSTR(TRANSLATED_DESCRIPTION, 1, 30), '...'))
       END AS PRODUCT_DESC_RU
FROM PRODUCT_DESCRIPTIONS;
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Also tag with the database you are using.

Comment: COALSECE(yourcolumn,'') - will either return yourcolumn if not NULL, or an empty string

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you want something like this:

```
SELECT PRODUCT_ID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN LANGUAGE_ID = 'US' THEN COALESCE(TO_CHAR(TRANSLATED_NAME), ' ')
           END) AS PRODUCT_NAME_US,
       MAX(CASE WHEN LANGUAGE_ID = 'US' THEN INITCAP(CONCAT(SUBSTR(TRANSLATED_DESCRIPTION, 1, 30), '...'))
           END) AS PRODUCT_DESC_US,
       MAX(CASE WHEN LANGUAGE_ID = 'RU' THEN COALESCE(TO_CHAR(TRANSLATED_NAME), ' ')
           END) AS PRODUCT_NAME_RU,
       MAX(CASE WHEN LANGUAGE_ID = 'RU' THEN INITCAP(CONCAT(SUBSTR(TRANSLATED_DESCRIPTION, 1, 30), '...'))
           END) AS PRODUCT_DESC_RU
FROM PRODUCT_DESCRIPTIONS
GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID; -- whatever each row defines
```

This does an explicit aggregation for each product (use the appropriate id of course), putting the English and Russian translations in the appropriate columns.

Comment: Thank you very much