# Not including null values

Tags: sql, database, oracle, null, coalesce

I'm trying to show data in English and Russian

```
SELECT temp.*
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN pd.LANGUAGE_ID = 'US' THEN COALESCE(TO_CHAR(pd.TRANSLATED_NAME), ' ')
                      END AS PRODUCT_NAME_US,
                      CASE WHEN pd.LANGUAGE_ID = 'US' THEN CONCAT(SUBSTR(pd.TRANSLATED_DESCRIPTION, 1, 30), '...')
                      END AS PRODUCT_DESC_US,
                      CASE WHEN pd.LANGUAGE_ID = 'RU' THEN COALESCE(TO_CHAR(pd.TRANSLATED_NAME), ' ')
                      END AS PRODUCT_NAME_RU,
                      CASE WHEN pd.LANGUAGE_ID = 'RU' THEN CONCAT(SUBSTR(pd.TRANSLATED_DESCRIPTION, 1, 30), '...')
                      END AS PRODUCT_DESC_RU,
                      CASE WHEN pin.WARRANTY_PERIOD = '00-00' THEN 'No Warranty'
                           WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM pin.WARRANTY_PERIOD) = '00'  THEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM pin.WARRANTY_PERIOD) || ' years'
                           WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM pin.WARRANTY_PERIOD) = '00' THEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM pin.WARRANTY_PERIOD) || ' months'
                           WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM pin.WARRANTY_PERIOD) <> '00' AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM pin.WARRANTY_PERIOD) <> '00' 
                           THEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM pin.WARRANTY_PERIOD) || ' years and ' || EXTRACT(MONTH FROM pin.WARRANTY_PERIOD) ||' months'
                           ELSE 'No Warranty'
                      END AS "Warranty", inv.QUANTITY_ON_HAND AS IN_STOCK
FROM PRODUCT_DESCRIPTIONS pd JOIN PRODUCT_INFORMATION pin
ON pd.PRODUCT_ID = pin.PRODUCT_ID
JOIN INVENTORIES inv
ON inv.PRODUCT_ID = pin.PRODUCT_ID) temp

WHERE temp.PRODUCT_NAME_US LIKE '%Monitor%' 
OR temp.PRODUCT_NAME_RU LIKE '%Монитор%' 
AND temp.IN_STOCK < 1000
ORDER BY temp.PRODUCT_NAME_US ASC, temp."Warranty" DESC;
```

But the result includes null values. How can I remove them?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rk1I.png)

Comment: Doesn't this answer also solve this problem?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44761935/removing-null-value-from-string.

Comment: Yeah but when I use it I get
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"

Answer (score 0):

Try by moving

WHERE temp.PRODUCT_NAME_US LIKE '%Monitor%' 
OR temp.PRODUCT_NAME_RU LIKE '%Монитор%'

inside inner query and use COALESCE in outer query